# How to count N pairs of a given list by going through it once?

Tags: python, nlp

Given a list of terms, like so:

```
['<s>', 'simon', 'is'. 'a', 'good', 'friend', '</s>', '<s>', 'simon', 'is', 'friend', '</s>']
```

Lets count the occurrences of each term. Easy.

```
def _add(t, T):
    if t in T:
        T[t] += 1
    else:
        T[t] = 1

for term in terms:
     _add(term, counts)
```

Giving me:

```
counts = { '<s>': 2, 'simon': 2, 'is': 2, 'a': 1, 'good': 1, 'friend': 2, '</s>': 2 }
```

Now what if I want to do the above, but during such list traversal, also count the occurrences of every pair (in tuple format) in this manner:

```
counts2 = { ('<s>', 'simon'): 2, ('simon', 'is'): 2, ('is', 'a'): 1, ('a', 'good'): 1, ('good', 'friend'): 1, ('friend', '</s>'): 2, ('simon', 'friend'): 1 }
```

As you can notice, I do not want to store tuples that contain a `'</s>'` and it's not the last element. That's easy enough...

```
for i, term in enumerate(terms):
        _add(term, counts)
        if not term == '</s>': _add((term, terms[i+1]), counts2)
```

The problem, and thus this question, is I can not think of a way to do this for N pairs. That is, store the occurrences of every tuple of N elements, while also storing the occurrences of N-1 tuples, N-2, ... and finally a tuple with element 1.

Is this even possible? Thanks.

Edit:

I developed an O(N*M) solution, where M is the terms' size and N is the N-Gram's size. Is it optimized as it could be?

```
def build_counts(n):
for i, term in enumerate(terms):
    t = ()
    for j in range(i, n+i):
        if j == len(terms): break;
        t = t + (terms[j],)
        if not len(t) in counts: counts[len(t)] = {}
        _add(t, counts[len(t)])
```

Comment: store the previous N-1 terms. A tuple can be a dictionary key. Why include <s> but exclude </s>?

Comment: I have working code based on maintaining a history list of length N, but you'll have to get closer before I post it. I used defaultdict(int) as the counter. Also you can use a tuple as a dictionary key. But mainly I just use history.append(term) and reset it on </s>

Comment: I arrived at a solution, but not sure if it is as optimized as it could be. Can you check my edit?

Comment: Looks good. Minor points: You forgot that you were going to ignore the start and end sentinels, and prevent tuples from spanning sentence boundaries.

Comment: If you set N=4 or more, you see things like ("friend", "<s>", "</s>", "simon")

Comment: Yes, I didn't do that yet (they were commented out) but thanks for reminding me! My friend and I are doubting how good this solution is, given how long it takes to evaluate the dataset.

Comment: Once you limit it by sentence boundaries, that also limits the size of the tuples you are building for some large N. It could just be the dataset, or there could be an inefficient python operation hidden in the loop (I checked a few of them and they were okay) But this discussion is more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ after you fix up those details.

Comment: Thanks, will post there!

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. It's working in good time. It was taking long because I was running vscode in debug mode and for some reason it was taking much longer.